# is it possible to put condition inside count function in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have a table with a `creditAmount` and `terminal_ID` fields, in which I have values that are >0 and some are < 0. I want to count the rows which are >0 and the terminal_id's of every record.

I tried this:

```
SELECT terminal_ID, COUNT(to_number(credit_amount)) AS count 
FROM isevaHarmsReports1 where to_number(credit_amount) > 0 group by  terminal_ID;
```

If I execute the above query it gives only count and terminal_ID of user of credit_amount > 0 but not which are < 0

```
if credit amount is < 0 I want only terminal_id
if credit amount is > 0 I want only terminal_id and count
```

How can I count rows based on a condition?

Comment: You need a conditional select, So i think you must go with a stored procedure.

Comment: It concerns me that you use `to_number(credit_amount)`. That is implying you are storing this value as a string. Is that correct, or is it really being stored as a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
select terminal_id, 
       count(case when credit_amount > 0 then 1 end) as count_gt0,  
       count(case when credit_amount < 0 then 1 end) as count_lt0 
from your_table
group by terminal_id
```

The `case` expression delivers `1` if credit_amount is in the range else `null`. The aggregation function `count` respects no null values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
SELECT terminal_id, COUNT(*)
   FROM isevaHarmsReports1
  WHERE TO_NUMBER(creditAmount) > 0
  GROUP BY terminal_id
UNION
SELECT terminal_id, NULL
   FROM isevaHarmsReports1
  WHERE TO_NUMBER(creditAmount) < 0
  GROUP BY terminal_id
```